# How to adjust the width of products in shipment pdf

Tags: magento-1.9, pdf

[image: adjusting table width]

In Shipment PDF I want to make this (qty, products, sku)table width 280 px according to the top box, but I can't change the width of the product name, it should be fix within the table, but it's exceeding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file that is responsible for this task is:

`code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Items/Invoice/Default.php`
OR

`code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Items/Invoice/Grouped.php`
OR

`code/core/Mage/Bundle/Model/Sales/Order/Pdf/Items/Invoice.php`

If it is simple product then first file, if grouped then second file and if it is bundle then last file.

You will need to check `draw()` function.
Basically you are editing `x-axis` value. For example by default for `Product Name` `x-axis` value is `35`.

Magento uses zend to create pdf. [Learn more about drawing lines in pdf](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.pdf.drawing.html).